# Cannot get CALayer to display in UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, calayer, caanimation

I have a simple, single-view app and for some reason I cannot get a `CALayer` to display in the app's `UIView`. The background color of the view is correct but the image in the `CALayer` is not visible. I've stepped through the code in the debugger and I'm sure that the image is being loaded correctly. If instead of using a `CALayer` I use a `UIImageView` everything works as you'd expect.

Here is the code from my `UIViewController` subclass. Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    CALayer* cardLayer = [self layerForCard];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:cardLayer];
}

- (CALayer *)layerForCard
{
    UIImage* cardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card1.jpg"];
    CGSize cardSize    = cardImage.size;
    CGRect cardRect    = CGRectMake(.0, .0, cardSize.width, cardSize.height);

    // Container Layer
    CALayer *containerLayer = [CALayer layer];
    containerLayer.bounds   = cardRect;
    containerLayer.opacity  = 1.0;

    // Image Layer
    CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.bounds = cardRect;
    imageLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
    imageLayer.contents = CFBridgingRelease(cardImage.CGImage);

    [containerLayer addSublayer:imageLayer];

    return containerLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either set the correct anchorpoints, or use

```
containerLayer.frame = cardRect;
..
imageLayer.frame = cardRect;
```

instead of

```
containerLayer.bounds = cardRect;
..
imageLayer.bounds = cardRect;
```